# Understanding resource loading in Java (Eclipse context)

Tags: java, resources, log4j

Here is the problem:

I have a java library with maven organization in which I created a log4j.xml file to dump logs when running Junit tests.

In the application that use the library, I have a batch mode (main + call to application) that creates its own ConsoleAppender when running with verbose parameter.

The problem is that even without verbose, I still "benefit" from the test resources log4j.xml file configuration (I changed the console name and put the log4j debug mode to be sure of this)

How comes that a test resource file, that is not even in the jar, can be loaded when running an application?

Everything is gradle managed

Comment: It's not, and everything is gradle managed (added to question)

Comment: As I understand it, Gradle is correct but Eclipse is not : Eclipse publish everything (main and test) in bin directory and that explains why the log4j.xml is "inherited" in another component